# Can't style Ajax script content (nowrap not working?)

Tags: html, css, ajax

I'm retrieving a script from a server that inserts a button enclosed in a label into the doc. I have two problems with this: I can't prevent a line break between the button and the button's label, and I can't find a way to do the styling outside the returned script itself.
Firebug shows this XHR response (I've inserted line breaks for readability):

```
document.getElementById("div-foo1").innerHTML="
     <label style='white-space:nowrap;'>
     <input type='button' id='sButton0' style='width:10px; height:20px;'>
     foo1
     </label>";
```

The first problem is that `white-space:nowrap` isn't preventing a line break between the button and the following 'foo1' label. I've also tried an enclosing `<nobr></nobr>`, with no difference. I know that the styling is generally working, because I can change the button width and see the change in the browser.

The second problem is that I can't find a way to get the styling out of the script. If I put this in the HTML header:

```
   <style>     
   #sButton0 { width:30px; height:20px; }
   </style>
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding display:inline; to the button's style (on the style tag)? I wonder if there is another css that is setting its display to block, which would cause the linebreak before the label text.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and thought that it had fixed the problem. However, it turned out that adding a 'float:left' to the style is sufficient to prevent the line break - no idea why. Checked on F/F, Opera, Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, just remove the style attribute from the  tag. It overrides the style in head.

Comment: and also I tried your js writing all html in one line like this:
`<label style='white-space:nowrap;'><input type='button' id='sButton0' >foo1</label>`
And there was no line break between input and "foo1".

Comment: I was actually doing this already when I tried the style - I should have made it clearer in the original post. I have simplified the problem, and removed the Ajax, so I'll ask again with a better question title...